# Matrix error out range

Tags: c#

The code talks about going into an matrix, splitting into a 9x9 matrix and performing operation.

The problem is that it is looking for element outside the matrix

What is the code error?

```
for (int x = 1; x < normal.Width-1; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < normal.Height-1; y++)
                {
                    contador = 0;

                    //loop para separa o que se vai calcular
                    for (int a = x - 1; a < x + 1; a++)
                    {
                        for (int i = y - 1; i < y + 1; i++)
                        {
                            rcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(x + a, y + i).R;
                            gcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(x + a, y + i).G;
                            bcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(x + a, y + i).B;

                            contador++;

                        }
                    }
                    r = medianacalc(rcalc);
                    g = medianacalc(gcalc);
                    b = medianacalc(bcalc);
```

Comment: Please change you tag to C# instead of C.

Answer (score 1):

`x` can be `normal.Width-2`

`a` could be as big as `x`

so, `x + a` can be `2*(normal.Width-2)` which can be out of range (bigger than `normal.Width`)

I guess you should say

```
(int)normal.GetPixel(x, y)
```

or

```
(int)normal.GetPixel(a, i)
```

instead of

```
(int)normal.GetPixel(x + a, y + i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're trying to iterate a 3x3 square around each `(x,y)` cell in the matrix (although your inner loops would only iterate a 2x2 square, but you said 9x9, and 3*3=9...).  In which case, the `a` and `i` (why not `b`?) loops should be either:

```
for (int a = -1; a <= 1; a++) {
    for (int b = -1; b <= 1; b++) {
        rcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(x + a, y + b).R;
        gcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(x + a, y + b).G;
        bcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(x + a, y + b).B;
        contador++;
    }
}
```

i.e. `(a,b)` is an offset around `(x,y)`.

Or:

```
for (int a = x-1; a <= x+1; a++) {
    for (int b = y-1; b <= y+1; b++) {
        rcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(a, b).R;
        gcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(a, b).G;
        bcalc[contador] = (int)normal.GetPixel(a, b).B;
        contador++;
    }
}
```

i.e. `(a,b)` is an absolute index into the matrix.